# How to display a window with a 3D object created using (three.js) in a certain place?

Tags: html, css

Please tell me how to display the project.

html

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>name</title>
    <style>
    body {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    }
    canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
    #program3d { 
    width: 400px; 
    height: 400px; 
    }
    </style>
 </head>

 <body> 
    <script src="js\Sistem\three.js"></script> 
    <script src="js\Loader\OBJLoader.js"></script>                       
    <script src="js\Sistem\TrackballControls.js"></script>      
    <script src="js\Sistem\mucode.js"></script>         





<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSHD4lDk5cupCKwwEl78HwEgL6lfk1WcsVq88FTSe2xpVGN_n4s" width="175px"/>             <br/>


<div id="program3d"></div>
<input type="button" id="B1" value="Start" name="button1"  onclick="A1(); style.display='none'"  ><br/>


<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSHD4lDk5cupCKwwEl78HwEgL6lfk1WcsVq88FTSe2xpVGN_n4s" width="175px"/>             <br/>
</body>


</html>
```

JS

```
function A1(){  

var scene  = new THREE.Scene();  
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(65,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000);  


container = document.getElementById( 'program3d' );  
document.body.appendChild( container );              


var render = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();              
render.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);  
container.appendChild( render.domElement );          

render.setClearColor ( 0xC8C7C7 );  

camera.position.z= 5;  
camera.position.x= 0;
camera.position.y= 0;

var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight ( 0xfffef5, 0.45 );  
scene.add (ambientLight);


var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight (0xfff2e8, 0.8 );  
directionalLight.position.set (0.1, 1, 0.2);
scene.add(directionalLight);

var light1 =new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 4 , 30);  
//scene.add (light1);

var light2 =new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 4 , 30);  
//scene.add (light2);

var light3 =new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 4 , 30);  
//scene.add (light3);

    var update = function (){

    var time = Date.now() * 0.0005;

    light1.position.x = Math.sin ( time * 0.7) * 30;
    light1.position.y = Math.cos ( time * 0.5) * 40;
    light1.position.z = Math.cos ( time * 0.3) * 30;

    light2.position.x = Math.cos ( time * 0.3) * 30;
    light2.position.y = Math.sin ( time * 0.5) * 40;
    light2.position.z = Math.sin ( time * 0.7) * 30;

    light3.position.x = Math.sin ( time * 0.7) * 30;
    light3.position.y = Math.cos ( time * 0.3) * 40;
    light3.position.z = Math.sin ( time * 0.3) * 30;

};



var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();       
var loader  = new THREE.ImageLoader(manager);   

var masif = [
THREE.OBJLoader, 
THREE.MMDLoader];

var meshes = [];  

var objLoader = new masif [0]();  

objLoader.load ('models/bas2.obj', function (object){  
    console.log(object);                             

    object.traverse (function (child)                
    {
    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh)
    {

        meshes.push(child);                          

    }   

    });

    var mesh1 = meshes [2]; 


    mesh1.position.y = 0;  

var textureBody = new THREE.Texture();  
loader.load ('tex/Base4.png', function (image){     
    textureBody.image = image;
    textureBody.needsUpdate = true;                  
    });


    var bumpMapBody = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('tex/untitled2-NM_u0_v0.tif');  

    mesh1.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({  

        wireframeLinecap : "round",
        wireframeLinejoin : "round",

        map: textureBody    

        });   

meshes.forEach(function(entry){  

            scene.add(entry);

        });

}); 

var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls (camera);

var rendering =function() {

    controls.update();  

    render.render(scene, camera);  

};

var GameLoop = function(){
    requestAnimationFrame (GameLoop);
    update();
    rendering();

};

GameLoop();

rendering();  



};
```

so that (canvas) is strictly in div program3d

and does not go beyond

I was able to transfer it to

container = document.getElementById ('program3d');

But for some reason, after clicking on the button, the window still flies to the end (body) And takes the whole page

Please tell me how to fix it.

http://static2.keep4u.ru/2018/10/17/6566af4d181bd622e8e.png

Comment: You could try to create that Object in JS and append it to the body, rather than having it somewhere and wanting to move it.

Comment: Something like `var container = document.createElement("div"); container.setAttribute("id" , "program3d"); //Do stuff with render; container.appendChild(render); body.appendChild(container);` ||| Look here: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) to see more about Elements in the DOM

Comment: I added a script, but it still came out at the end of the body.
He just created a div tag which is 400 by 400
Canvas still got 1600 by 800

Comment: Ok please specify exactly what you want it to look like, and where. Because I thought you wanted to put it at the end of the Body. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to be able to output it where I need it.
For example
I need to bring it inside the tag div id="program3d"
Between Two Pictures
size to  400px 400px http://static2.keep4u.ru/2018/10/17/2348385e3c6bf37ee1d.jpg

Comment: Ok, you have to tell the canvas to be 400x400 or 100% of its parent (which would be div program3d) if this is set to 400x400. And then just get rid off `body.appendChild(container)`. If you want the container to stay right where you defined it, then appending the render should do the trick. The rest is just sizing with attribute values or even CSS (could stretch or blur, so I'd try to define the canvas within your 3D Properties)

Comment: Keep in mind that defining `var container = document.GetElementById("program3d");` only creates a variable that holds information about that object. So you didn't _transfer_ it with this call, so there is no need to append it again. Therefore forget about appending the container.

Comment: I have already tried to prescribe styles in canvas
400px to 400px
But the Site still ignores it.


When trying to insert code
`var container = document.GetElementById("program3d");`
gives an error message
document.GetElementById is not a function
    at A1
And if I delete
`document.body.appendChild(container)`
That window is not reproducible at all.

Comment: `render.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight); ` to `render.setSize(400, 400); `. That'll describe your render space to 400x400. 
deleting `document.body.appendChild(container)` should have no effect, if you have `<div id="program3d"></div>` already in your html. `GetElementById` has to be written with a small `g`, my bad. If you still have problems, I suggest you wrap yourself around the basics of web-development before trying to develop a whole game from start in hope the lib being easy enough to develop without any knowledge.

Comment: thank you for explaining `var container = document.getElementById( 'program3d' );``render.setSize(window.innerWidth= 400  , window.innerHeight = 400 ); `

Comment: `window.innerWidth = 400` is not the way to go. With that you assign a value of 400 to the window.innerWidth attribute, but that attribute holds the information about the window you're displaying at. Just use `render.setSize(400, 400);`